# Obtener identificador de dispositivo único con javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy trabajando en mi TFG para la Universidad en un aplicación en el que es necesario un identificador de dispositvo único. Estoy trabajando con javascript y la aplicación (que es accesible al descargarse la app o al entrar en la página web) correría en las siguientes plataformas de ejecución:

- móviles y tablets: Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Firefox OS, Tizen
- smart TV: Android, Tizen OS, Web OS
- browsers: Windows, Mac, Linux

Mi pregunta es si ¿es posible obtener un identificador del dispositivo físico como podría ser la MAC pero que no cambie nunca (ya que la MAC la puede cambiar el usuario cuando quiera) para todas o, por lo menos, para alguna de las plataformas de ejecución mencionadas antes?

Comment: Lo siento, pero ya lo he intentado yo antes, no se puede obtener con javascript la mac del cliente

Comment: Generalmente javascript puede acceder a los recursos del usuario que lo ejecuta, el navegador hace de puente y no permite acceder a información del hardware por seguridad. Siempre puedes poner un applet en java que te resuelva esta información y la puedas usar en javascript. El motivo es por seguridad. Te paso un par de enlaces con algunas soluciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531000/javascript-access-to-hardware (usando activeX) y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928367/how-to-enable-user-log-in-from-the-only-one-machineby-acquiring-cpu-serial-to

Answer (score 1):

Me temo que no existe una forma definitiva de identificar un dispositivo por el mero hecho de que esta información en el fondo es un conjunto de bytes en una memoria que se puede modificar.

Aunque encontraras un dato que estuviera realmente grabado a fuego y no se pudiera cambiar, el software de la máquina puede interceptar el envío de este dato y modificarlo antes de que salga por la tarjeta de red. Aunque eso no pudiera hacerse, nada impide interponer un medio que sí lo haga (como un router modificado que se sitúe en medio de la comunicación).

Con esto en mente, te recomiendo alternativas que, aunque no sean infalibles (pues en mi opinión ninguna lo es), permiten alcanzar tu objetivo:

Te recomiendo que tu servidor y tu cliente negocien un identificador y que éste sea almacenado en algún lugar en el que pueda persistir, tanto en el cliente como en el servidor.

En tu servidor yo almacenaría los identificadores registrados en una tabla de una base de datos.

En los clientes web, este id se guardaría como una cookie o en el local storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

En los clientes nativos (como apps), guardaría la el identificador del dispositivo donde te sea permitido (como el sistema de ficheros o, si quieres algo más sofisticado, una bb.dd. de SQL lite).

Ejemplo:

Alicia se conecta mediante su navegador web.

1. Establece una solicitud de identificación al servidor. Busca en su localstorage y no encuentra un identificador, así que la solicitud no tiene un identificador como parámetro.
2. El servidor genera un identificador (por ejemplo el "#dfefwer234"). El servidor almacena el identificador en la base de datos.
3. El servidor devuelve el identificador. El cliente lo recibe y lo guarda en su localStorage.

La próxima vez que Alicia se conecte encontrará su identificador en su localstorage y hará la solicitud con "#dfefwer234". El servidor sabe que el dispositivo con id "#dfefwer234" se ha conectado.

Consideraciones:

1. Lo ideal es que las solicitudes y respuestas estén protegidas (puedes usar SSL, por ejemplo) para garantizar la privacidad de la comunicación.
2. Tu algoritmo de generación de id debe de ser capaz de generar un gran abanico de ids que hagan dificil la labor de simular otros ids (Te recomiendo ids que tengan 256 o más bits).

Hay más consideraciones, pero no son tan importantes, si estás interesada coméntame y las expongo.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Creo que debería ser la respuesta aceptada. Desde mi punto de vista el OP ya sabía a lo que se enfrentaba (si una MAC se puede cambiar.. que no se puede?) Generar un token negociado parece la mejor opción, aunque evidentemente el usuario podría borrarlo. El usuario siempre va a poder desligar su dispositivo de su sesión anterior.

Answer (score 0):

En smart tv puedes obtener el id del dispositivo desde javascript, la forma varía según que librerías utilices (webOS, Tizen, Toast, etc):

- webOS -> http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/device-unique-id/
- Toast -> https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-plugin-toast/wiki/Tizen-API:-ProductInfo

En browsers no es posible obtener el id del dispositivo, existen librerías que lo simulan pero el id generado puede variar con tan modificar una de los parámetros usados como es el lenguaje del navegador

https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

En android y IOS supongo que también se podrá obtener de alguna manera ya que nativamente creo que se puede pero nunca lo he probado.